# htaccess php flags and load time

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've added some php flags in my htaccess in order to change some php 
config settings

as I dont have access to the .ini file

I'm wondering what effect that has on my website load speed,

is it slower?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it slower?

You tell me. Why don't you measure it? You could use the [apache bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) tool to see how making that change effects the number of requests per second you can do.

Chances are anything you do in your code is dramatically slower than a few `.htaccess` changes.

Answer (score 2):

The act of reading the .htaccess file is negligible.
There shouldn't be any noticeable slowdown in that regard.

If you're noticing a slowdown, one of your settings changes probably did it.

Answer (score 2):

If there is any difference, I don't think it's noticeable enough to be worried. Reading the .htaccess file and setting a directive is very lightweight operation compared to the whole process of executing a PHP script.